# Is it possible for me to restart a gif with CSS (no JS)?

Tags: html, css

So I have a piece of CSS like this:

```
.three-image-widget div.hover-icon img.original { display: block; }
.three-image-widget div.hover-icon img.hovered { display: none; }
.three-image-widget div.hover-icon:hover img.original { display: none; }
.three-image-widget div.hover-icon:hover img.hovered { display: block; }
```

I have `.original` images as `.png`s and the `.hovered` images are animated `.gif`s that I want to start, when hovering over the `div.hover-icon` elements. I know it's possible to do this with a JavaScript hack like this:

```
$('div.hover-icon').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.original').hide(); 
    var hov = $(this).find('.hovered'), 
        copy = hov.attr('src'); 
        hov.attr('src','').attr('src',copy);
});
```

but can I do the equivalent with pure CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't. You need to reload the GIF and CSS cannot do this.

Comment: Ok. I tought maybe it was possible given that it's possible to change `href`s with CSS.

Comment: CSS is for presentation. You cannot modify the document object model with it sorry :( feel free to [accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing I could figure out with pure CSS is changing URL on `:hover` but it will only reset once:

```css
div {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/6wffOji.gif);
  height:50px;
  width: 100px;
}

div:hover {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/6wffOji.gif?v=1);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

This approach would require you to use `background-image` instead of `<img>` tag.

---

**Edit:** Another method would be converting the GIF images to a 1 column sprite, where each frame is placed in a row, under each other, then use CSS `@keyframes` and `animation` to have better control over the image animation, you could reverse, alternate, control duration etc.

Simple GIF (animated):

[image: basic gif animation]

GIF sprite (no animation, static image):

[image: gif animation sprite]

Code:

```css
div {
  height:50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/3YMNTbS.gif);
}

div:hover {
  animation: gif steps(6) 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes gif {
  to {background-position: 0 100%;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

As you can see, the `:hover` state fires the `gif` animation keyframes. the `steps(n)` function is the key here, it will iterate through the frames in steps instead of a continuous transition. `n` is the number of frames in your sprite.

I used [SpritePlane](https://github.com/mediochrea/SpritePlane) to generate the sprite with Photoshop. It's easy to create a sprite and the size is about the same, you could save a JPEG for more compression or PNG for smooth alpha channel (also can be compressed).